# I migrated my app to react router dom v6. URL params show the desired ID but the component loads a not found component and then blank page on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I previously had a callback function that used `history.push` and with the migration I am now using `navigate` instead. When I click to render the desired component, it takes me to my fall back component with the url displaying the id. On refresh the page is a blank screen.

How it was before:

```
const handleClickRow = useCallback(id => {
  history.push(`product_details/${id}`);
}, [history]);
```

How it is now:

```
const handleClickRow = useCallback(id => {
  navigate(`product_details/${id}`);
}, [navigate]);
```

The Route SetUp:

```
<Route 
  path={`/product_details/:id(${uuid_regular_expression})`}
  element={
    <PrivateRoute >
      <ProductsDetailsPage />
    </PrivateRoute>
  }
/>
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with this specific code. Are there any errors in the console? Can you provide a more complete [mcve] and exact reproduction steps?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. It shouldn't tell your whole story.

Comment: @DrewReese no errors shown in the console, just displays a component that isn't the one I want. If I refresh however, I get a blank page.

Comment: I think we'd need to see a more complete [mcve] to dig any further on this; there's just simply not enough context here to say why routes/routed content are having rendering issues. If you could, also try to stand up a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.